# Login URL in sentry 6.1.2

Tags: python, nginx, sentry

I deployed a sentry instance. I set up "SENTRY_URL_PREFIX" as "http://server.com/sentry" however, whenever I point browser to "http://server.com/sentry", it redirects me to "http://server.com/login". I'm serving sentry with nginx. Here is an excerpt of the configuration:

```
    location /sentry {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8006;
    }
```

If I change the location from `/sentry` to `/` everything works as expected, but with the former the login url is outside that location (in `/login`).

I expect all uris used in sentry remains in that location, because, there are other projects running in the same virtual site.

Is there any way to get the login url in the prefix location?